# Identifying X-Y coordinates from a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1

I need to find the high and low values of multiple raster datasets individually. Then determine the x,y location of these values.  I am using ArcGIS 10.1, have built the mosaic datasets I need, and have determined the locations of the high and low values (estimations are fine).  However I cannot determine the X,Y location for these values (points).

I know there is a "Find x-y" tool, but I need the opposite.  Is there a way to point click and return the x-y for that location?

With vector data I could populate a field with x-y values, however I do not have the time to cut out the raster datasets individually and turn them into vector data to do this.

There must be another way?

Comment: I think I found a workaround:

Created new feature class, populated two columns with LAT, LONG and calculated geometry.  
Not exactly what I had in mind, but this will do for the time being

Comment: Similar questions have been answered in other threads (but they are difficult to search for, unfortunately). *Eg*, you can create grids of x and y values and simply query those grids. This doesn't even require manual intervention, because values in one grid (such as the indicator of the extremes of an input grid) can be used to query values of another grid which it overlays. Such a solution would be efficient when you have many overlaid raster datasets. When they are not overlaid, or there are few of them, converting that *indicator grid* (not the original!) to features is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Get Raster Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m7000000) to determine min and max values.  Then a conditional statement in [raster calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000) will create a raster of these values.  These cells can then be [converted to points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000007000000).

This can easily be implemented in Model Builder or a python script to save time whenever this needs to be done.